# Appropriate usage for "Je les ai .." vs "Je leur ai"

Tags: pronoms, verbes, suisse

These two phrases never cease to confuse me. I always say:

- *Je les ai envoyeur mon message*
- *Je les ai dit de ne pas me perturber*
- *Je les avais fait comprendre la phrase ...*

So on so forth. I can not distinguish when it is appropriate to use "*Je leur ai...*".

For me, "*Je les ai..*" sounds a lot similar in meaning to "*I ... them*"

Is there some sort of mnemonical solution to understand their use-cases?

Comment: To correct your 3 sentences, which are wrong : «Je **leur** ai envoy**é** mon message», «Je **leur** ai dit de ne pas me perturber», «Je **leur** avais fait comprendre la phrase»

Comment: In English, "them" (as in "I sent them my message") can be an *indirect* object. In French, it's *leur*. Them sometimes is a direct object in English, as in "I gave them back to you yesterday." Then it is *les* in French.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me correct the phrases you mentioned:

- *Je **leur** ai envoyé mon message*
- *Je **leur** ai demandé de ne pas me perturber*
- *Je **leur** avais fait comprendre la phrase*

Now, let's come back to your question: you are confused with *leur* and *les*.

There is one simple rule that makes a huge difference between them and which will help you to distinguish definitely between them:

1. Remember that ***leur*** is the plural of ***lui***. It always has the role of [***complément d'objet indirect***](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d'objet_indirect).
2. Les plays  always the role of [***complément d'objet direct***](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d'objet_direct). Examples:

   - *Je **les** ai mangés*: I have eaten them
   - *Elle **les** a oubliées*: She has forgotten them

Comment: Nice explanation! This is off-topic, but I notice that with “leur”/coi there’s no agreement/accord with compound verbs, but with “les”/cod there is.  Is the extra “e” in oublié**e**s there because the cod “les” is replacing multiple feminine things (this is my guess) or is it somehow related to the feminine subject (Elle)? Also ( and even further off-topic, please forgive me), in “Je les ai envoyé(?**s**?)+ infinitive [chier, par exemple!] (where it seems that “envoyer” doesn’t require a oi/coi), should there be agreement with ‘les’=envoyé[e]**s**?  Thanks!

Comment: Your question is on topic, do not worry. Nice that you noticed *oubliées* : yes, I supposed she has forgotten ***lot of feminine things*** as you said :) It does not refer to *Elle*. I did it by intention to highlight you the idea of COD when it comes to *les*.  For **2nd** question: we say *envoyées* or *envoyés* depending on what you sent: *feminine things* then use the first,  but use the last for *masculine things*

Answer (score 6):

There's no mnemonic - it's a question of whether the [French verb needs *à*](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/verbs-with-a/). *Envoyer* and *dire* do - *envoyer quelque chose à qqun* and *dire quelque chose à qqun*, so your first two are wrong. The correct grammar is

*Je leur ai envoyé...*

*Je leur ai dit...*

But the [causative](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/faire-causative/) doesn't take *à* unless there's also a direct object. So *je leur ai fait comprendre la phrase* but *je les ai fait comprendre*.

Comment: Il faut toujours envisager le contexte : Dire quelque chose *à quelqu'un*, c'est lui parler ;  *à* désigne un mouvement vers -- Dire quelque chose *de quelqu'un*, c'est parler de cette personne à une autre personne ; *de* désigne un mouvement *à partir de*.

Comment: This is a good example. I will see if I get more of the same before I accept it. So, for example, if I was to use the word *reconter*, since it is used as *raconter qqun* this means, the right form to use would be *Je les ai ranconte*?

Comment: No, once again, it's *raconter qqchose à qqun*, so *Je leur ai raconté*. Here's an example with *les*: *Je les ai écoutés* because in French it's *écouter* not *"écouter à."*

Comment: On the other hand, if it's "to tell something" (e.g., the stories), it would be *je les ai racontés*. Basically, it's question of direct object (*les*) vs indirect object (*leur*).

Comment: Its simply a matter of knowing which verbs use «à», which «de», which both, or which sometimes. For a learner, sometimes memorization helps but the real key is practice and correct practice. After 4 years of french, «je les ai envoyé mon message» hits my eat funny. I gave my message them? __To__ them, thus «je leur ai ...»

Comment: Pour la troisième phrase, le modèle est plutôt _faire comprendre qqchose à qq'un_, donc l'exemple est erroné: on dit plutôt _"je leur avais fait comprendre la phrase"_.

Comment: Oui, tout à fait. J'ai effacé mon erreur.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb (the other answers are more complete and will also explain the why):

> *Je leur ai fait une faveur.* = I made them a favor. = I made a favor **to** them.
>   *Mes devoirs, je les ai faits.* = My homework, I did it. = I did <s>to</s> my homework.

If you are speaking of something receiving the action (COI, see [Begueradj's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16298/7224)), then you will use ***leur***. If the pronoun is the object of the action (COD, same answer), then you will use ***les***.